# Azure AD Custom Identity Issuer without @ sign

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Currently our team has a web app and we use Angular as frontend and have azure app service for our backend API. We sorted our authentication with following the docs and it worked fine so far. We use code flow and our users are added to our AD in the azure portal.

If they land on our front end they are redirected to microsofts login page and are able to login with for example

```
user@myappdomain.com
password
```

One small thing I am not able to find in the documentation and is a requirement by clients, is it possible to login ( get an access token for our API ) with a login name without @ sign or Identity Issuer.

For example:

```
userfromcompanyx
password
```

Excuse in advance for misused or wrongly interpreted jargon as English is not my native tongue. Does anyone have experience in this specific use case or can point me in the right direction? Appreciate all replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not  supported with Azure AD

For you are scenario you can go with Azure Ad b2c where you can log in with a username  or phone number without using an email id

Comment: Thank you for your reply, currently investigating combining our companies AD with Azure Ad b2c !